# Azure VM SQL Connection Fail

Tags: sql, azure, virtual-machine, azure-vm-role

I have created a SQL VM which I can connect via Management Tools locally. However, my .NET application can't connect to it. The VM is part of a cloud service. I am wondering if my connection string is wrong, or if I need to create a certain end point.[This is an image of Connection String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6J86.jpg)

Comment: just make sure all IP addresses are allowed

Comment: But since I am able to connect to it via SQL Management tools from the same machine/ip. Just not the code.

Comment: What error are you getting back from the connection when it fails?